# XAML/UWP: Customizing AutoSuggestBox ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm developing an application which will consume an API and bring back the results, so I'm using AutoSuggestBox to implement the suggestions. For designing purposes, I needed to customize each Suggestion Item, as following the [AutoSuggestBox Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox?view=winrt-19041) it says to create a custom ItemTemplate.

I want to make the DataTemplate's grid fill the whole suggestion space, but still, I couldn't make it work.

The Grid seems to set its width in a arbitrary way based on the child's size, check it out:

The code:

```
<AutoSuggestBox 
        Name="inputBox" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center" PlaceholderText="Search or paste your video link here."
        BorderBrush="#7D1B0A" MinHeight="32"
        KeyDown="HandleEnterPress" TextChanged="inputBox_TextChanged" SuggestionChosen="inputBox_SuggestionChosen" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ListItems, Mode=OneWay}">
        <AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="#C92306" BorderBrush="#7D1B0A" BorderThickness="1, 0, 1, 1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="150">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding VideoTitle}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="#FFFFFF"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ChannelTitle}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Foreground="#FFFFFF"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
    </AutoSuggestBox>
```

The rendered version of it:
[AutosuggestBox Suggestion rendered behavior with grid not filling all the available space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGbdb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is due to the suggestion list container of `AutoSuggestBox`, please insert the following code in `AutoSuggestBox`:

```xml
<AutoSuggestBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    </Style>
</AutoSuggestBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Thanks.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you. It only needed to set the ItemContainerStyle's Background to the desired color and then it come to the desired result! :)